# Sorting a list of strings into a richtextbox VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, sorting

I'm reading a lot of values from some registry keys from a backgroundworker. I loop through multiple keys and if the value contains specific text I append the value in the key to a richtextbox.

I'm appending the text into the richtextbox using a reportprogress event. Is there any way to sort this data in the richtextbox or possibly add the strings to an array and sort before appending it into the richtextbox?

Comment: Yes, add them to a List(Of String) then call the Sort method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code snippet to do this operation

```
    Dim textLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    textLines = RichTextBox1.Lines.ToList()
    textLines.Sort()
    RichTextBox1.Text = String.Join(Chr(13), textLines.ToArray)
```

Please include this lines in a function and call at the time of insertion of new Lines to the `richtextbox`

Comment: Awesome this is good is there a way to filter out empty lines when doing this sort?